# Unable to get Actuator's measurements [ "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME" ] in Graphite server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, graphite

I have a micro-service with spring-boot-2.2.4 with actuator. When I hit the `/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests` url, I'm getting below response.

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": "milliseconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 77.0
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 2272.891396
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0.0
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "None"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "uri",
            "values": [
                "/queue/{queueId}",
                "/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "SUCCESS"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "200"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In **graphite server** I'm able to get the `count` details but I'm unable to get the `TOTAL_TIME` metrics details. Can someone please help me to figure out this issue. Where can I get this `TOTAL_TIME` in graphite server UI.